# Want a new column to show the rank of ordering books of a mem_id for a book according to date

Tags: php, mysql

I want a new rank column to show the rank; according to date for a book order of a member

[image]

Comment: so you want book `id=5` to be the first because it has smallest `date`? but what do you mean by `rank` ? you want dynamically set `rank` pseudo column to 1 for that record?

Comment: `id=5` has smallest date for `book_id=ACC-7272` but `id=6` also smallest for `book_id=J2mE`. I want a new column `rank` which shows, `rank=1` for `id=6` ; `rank=2` for `id=7` and `rank=1` for `id=5`

Comment: `id=5`has `date=2015-10-23 23:34:59` and `id=6` has `date=2015-10-23 23:34:59` so `id=5` has smaller `date` why should they have same `rank=1` you want rank to be based only on **DATE** part of yout taimestamps? like `2015-10-23`?

Comment: because `id=5` & `id=6` has same `mem_id` but different `book_id`; And `id=6` & `id=7` has same `book_id`, but `mem_id=M21212111018` has smallest `date`. that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is still not very clear.

But here is my approach (you should replace `mem_records` with your real table name):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6be133/3

```
SELECT t.*, t_rank.rank
FROM mem_records t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t_ord.*,
        @rank:= IF(@rank IS NULL,1,@rank+1) `rank`
  FROM (
        SELECT mem_id, 
              MIN(`date`) rank_date
        FROM mem_records
        GROUP BY mem_id
        ORDER BY rank_date
  ) t_ord
) t_rank
ON t.mem_id = t_rank.mem_id
```

Comment: These are two links. I just want like this :
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1514942872153187&set=pcb.1079896638688312&type=3&theater" title="M21212111018">Student Profile - M21212111018</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1514942898819851&set=pcb.1079896638688312&type=3&theater" title="M21212111019">Student Profile - M21212111019</a>